# RabbitMQ IOError: Socket closed

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a RabbitMQ message broker and a remote Celery worker. It is working fine but about every five minutes I get this error:

```
[2014-01-06 14:02:27,247: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 270, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 786, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 72, in asynloop
    next(loop)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 333, in create_loop
    cb(*cbargs)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line 156, in on_readable
    reader(loop)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line 141, in _read
    drain_events(timeout=0)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 282, in drain_events
    chanmap, None, timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 345, in _wait_multiple
    channel, method_sig, args, content = read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 316, in read_timeout
    return self.method_reader.read_method()
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 195, in read_method
    raise m
IOError: Socket closed
[2014-01-06 14:02:27,308: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ValueError('I/O operation on closed epoll fd',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 206, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 373, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 270, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 468, in start
    c.connection = c.connect()
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 369, in connect
    conn.transport.register_with_event_loop(conn.connection, self.hub)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 124, in register_with_event_loop
    loop.add_reader(connection.sock, self.on_readable, connection, loop)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 214, in add_reader
    return self.add(fds, callback, READ | ERR, args)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 165, in add
    self.poller.register(fd, flags)
  File "/usr/local/ABCD/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/eventio.py", line 78, in register
    self._epoll.register(fd, events)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed epoll fd
```

This is the init script I use to start a Celery deamon:

```
# description "Celery worker using sync broker"

console log

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid yoyo_login
setgid yoyo_login

script
chdir /usr/local/ABCD/abcdegg
exec /usr/local/ABCD/venv/bin/celery worker -n ABCD_sync.%h -A proj.sync_celery -Q sync_queue -l info --autoscale=10,3 --autoreload --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat
end script

respawn
```

Any idea why this error keep happening every few minutes?

Comment: same happen without upstart ?

Comment: @Guy Yes. Happens when I run the deamon without upstart as well. Sometimes I also get: exchange.declare: connection closed unexpectedly

Comment: Happens to me when broker heartbeats are configured and worker is idle (no messages in queue). Any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the worker is not the issue here, rather it seems RabbitMQ is closing the connection which the worker consumes. Check RabbitMQ/queue itself settings. Perhaps a proxy in the middle?